# How do I get SPSS syntax to return the variable type (e.g., string, numerical)?

Tags: syntax, spss

I'm writing syntax in SPSS and need to create logic statements and loops that are based on the variable type. Could someone suggest to me the code for SPSS Syntax to return variable type? Thank you!

Comment: To my knowledge, that is only possible using a scripting facility (python or R). Do you have them installed ?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51033797/how-can-i-check-the-measure-nominal-ordinal-scale-of-a-variable-using-syntax/51040103#51040103) answer will probably help you

Answer (score 0):

It's only an indirect way of working with variable information:
You could combine'codebook' with 'oms'. Like that, you'll get a new dataset with all the variable information as separat variables. After the needed transformations, you can merge the new dataset to the original.

```
    DATASET DECLARE v_information.
    OMS
    /SELECT TABLES /IF SUBTYPES ='Variable Information' /DESTINATION FORMAT=SAV OUTFILE=v_information VIEWER=YES.
    CODEBOOK test1 test2  /varinfo format.
    OMSEND.
```